# ViewPager onPageSelected set tab to initial state

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-webview

I have four tabs and a `ViewPager`. On each tab I have a `WebView`. What I want is to set the `WebView` to it's first page whenever the tab is selected.
This is what I have tried :

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {                        
    actionBar.getTabAt(position).select();
    if(position == 0) {
    ActivityFragment fr = (ActivityFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
    WebView view = fr.browser;
    if(view.canGoBack())
        view.goBack();
}
else if(position == 1) {
    GroupFragment fr = (GroupFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
    WebView view = fr.browser;
    if(view.canGoBack())
        view.goBack();
}
else if(position == 2) {
    MessageFragment fr = (MessageFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(2);
    WebView view = fr.browser;
    if(view.canGoBack())
        view.goBack();
```

}
   else if(position == 3) {
        NotificationFragment fr = (NotificationFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(3);
        WebView view = fr.browser;
        if(view.canGoBack())
            view.goBack();
   }
}

But `if(view.canGoBack())` never comes true. I know I can do this by setting `loadUrl` but I don't want to reload the `WebView`. That shall be my last option.

**PagingAdapter getItem**

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        try {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    // Top Rated fragment activity
                    return Fragment.instantiate(context, ActivityFragment.class.getName());
                case 1:
                    // Games fragment activity
                    return Fragment.instantiate(context, GroupFragment.class.getName());
                case 2:
                    // Movies fragment activity
                    return Fragment.instantiate(context, MessageFragment.class.getName());
                case 3:
                    return Fragment.instantiate(context, NotificationFragment.class.getName());
//                case 4:
//                    return Fragment.instantiate(context, FlyoutFragment.class.getName());
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return  null;
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please show `getItem` method from Adapter

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put code something like this for the **WebView**

Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history

```
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
    view.goBack();
    return true;
}
```